# Why won't adding a nonce to my plaintext help defeat cryptanalysis?

Tags: cryptography

Disclaimer: I assume this is a dumb idea, I'm asking for an explanation as to *why* it's a dumb idea :)

Let's say I that before encrypting a file, I pick a random number `x` between 0 and a constant `y`. I then pad my plaintext with `x` random bytes before, and `y-x` bytes after, so that the filesize doesn't give away x. I add the actual value of x to my buffer before running my normal encryption routine.

This would mean that encrypting the same plaintext with the same key would rarely produce the same encrypted output, without adding much work to either encryption or decryption.

Intuitively, I feel like this should be quite handy in reducing weakness to cryptanalysis, but I've never read of its mention, so I'm guessing it doesn't. Can anybody explain to me why this would be so?

Comment: You mean salt? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)  or perhaps padding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's not a bad idea and it is being used. Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29 and especially at a couple of papers from this google scholar search:
[http://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=random+padding+cryptanalysis](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=random%20padding%20cryptanalysis) (a lot of them are freely available, just click the pdf link on the right).

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that padding as defined by those wikipedia pages is more about fitting content into fixed block sizes than any additional security, Although my idea may just be a roundabout method of implementing an [initialisation vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).

Comment: You are right. As i understood your question, you want to prevent "that the filesize doesn't give away x". And the first paragraph of the wikipedia article actually adresses it. Also your goal, again as i understood your question was, to prevent that the same plaintext after encryption produces the same encrypted text. This goes more towards the initialization vector like it is being used for example by OpenSSL cbc, cfb, ofb modes. But overall it can be stated, that your idea was quite good and it can be used for the goals you are trying to achieve ;).

Comment: There are some other cases of turning a deterministic encryption to a probabilistic one by using padding like with rsa's [Optimal asymmetric encryption padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) and [Probabilistic Signature Scheme](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2005).

Answer (score 1):

I would say the correct answer here is "it depends." I know that's probably not what your looking for, but consider this.

1. Is your encrypted data just a small bit of information (say a number between 0 and 2^32), If this piece of information is part of a large algorithm I can just bruteforce the whole algorithm and ignore your encrypted data altogether.
2. What is "key" or secret to this ciphertext. You can pad all you want, but if you secret key is "7", then all the padding in the world wont help you. (This is analogous to small passwords + salt. Salt is not helping if your password space is simply 3 ASCII characters)
3. What mode of encryption are you operating in? If you are in ECB mode, this padding can help immensely and is basically required. Other modes of operation (OFB, CTR, ...) will basically pad the data for you, such that the encryption of the same file over and over again will produce different ciphertext.

I would offer up the simple answer that from a cryptographic point of view it never hurts to pad the data...

Comment: Thanks for that. The answer is always "it depends", but so long as there's some included "... on X", all is good.